# SSMS search database name?

Tags: sql-server, database, search

On a common mssql server, when there are too many databases, I find it difficult to find the database I created, is there a way to search the database name the SSMS?

Comment: select * from sysdatabases

Comment: You can also use the filter by right clicking the Databases node. Google search [result](https://www.google.com/search?q=filter+database+name+ssms+image&pws=0&gl=us&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj13IKHvdLXAhUICBoKHSl8D7cQ_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=959#imgrc=mrUQlsIjmevQ6M:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the tables folder of the database you are interested in.  Select "filter" and then "filter settings."  Once here you can search on various criteria.

Answer (score 1):

```
select name from sys.databases WHERE name=?
```

Comment: But I need to find my object explorer